# How to send a alert command from flask to html?

Tags: python, html, flask

I have route in my flask code where i do some database queries and based on that i render the template with appropriate data.
How can i send a command from flask to html so that the html file will alert(pop up) when it gets that command.

```
@app.route('/addqueue',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def addqueue():
    with sql.connect("database.db") as con:
       cur = con.cursor()
       con.row_factory = sql.Row
       cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM stability_tests WHERE devices=?''',(dname,))
       r = cur.fetchall()
       #check for some condition in r and issue alert in html page
    return render_template('queue.html')
```

Comment: do you mean flashing the alert ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using [flaskSocketio](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
By opening a socket on frontend and emit message from flask depends on your conditions

Answer (score 0):

queue.html is the file that returns to the user browser ? 
if so, what about adding embedded javascript code for alert :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> ..... 
<script type="text/javascript">alert("Data received");</script>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should alert only when some condition occurs at the backend(in flask).